# gentelella angular admin panel - gentelella toggle menu and sidebar click event not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, gentelella

I am developing an application on angularJS with gentelella admin panel. I have some issues.

```
 <div class="nav toggle">
    <a href="javascript:;" id="menu_toggle"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
 </div>
```

this is html snippet. but toggling not working. I have checked all loaded js files. there I have found 
`$MENU_TOGGLE.on('click')`
but it is not firing.

**EDIT**
this code from gentelella/custom.js

```
var $MENU_TOGGLE = $('#menu_toggle');
$MENU_TOGGLE.on('click', function() {
        console.log('clicked - menu toggle');

        if ($BODY.hasClass('nav-md')) {
            $SIDEBAR_MENU.find('li.active ul').hide();
            $SIDEBAR_MENU.find('li.active').addClass('active-sm').removeClass('active');
        } else {
            $SIDEBAR_MENU.find('li.active-sm ul').show();
            $SIDEBAR_MENU.find('li.active-sm').addClass('active').removeClass('active-sm');
        }

    $BODY.toggleClass('nav-md nav-sm');

    setContentHeight();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the correct scripts on the page. The original scripts. I removed a script and it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

check the order of how cdn and jquery files are loaded...moving that from bottom to head of the layout default helps me

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 <a href="javascript:;"id="menu_toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
```

Or you can prefer [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcdtest/HDQNs/)